# r shiny "An error has occurred" "The application failed to start."

Tags: r, shiny

When I test ran my server.R, ui.R, and global.R, it worked fine. When I published it on the shinyapps.io and tried running it, it gave me the error message with no sign of what went wrong.

Here is my Github: https://github.com/ryuth/shiny-MLBpitchFX_velocity/tree/master

When the codes are functional, what could have gone wrong in the shinyapps.io server? Are there any adjustments to make?

Comment: try looking into the debug console ouput on your web browser. It's probably a missing library or something.

Comment: Can you please copy the output of `shinyapps::showLogs()`?

Comment: I can just add 'shinyapps::showLogs()' just the way it is on my script and load it on server, right?

Comment: or could I also use "options(shiny.trace=TRUE)"?

Comment: I went to my shinyapps.io account and went to log. It gave me these: (Would this help?)

Comment: 2015-07-30T20:30:14.100030+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2015-07-30T20:31:21.864839+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: R version: 3.2.1
2015-07-30T20:31:21.864900+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: shiny version: 0.12.1
5-07-30T20:31:21.865191+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2015-07-30T20:31:22.054914+00:00 shinyapps[53094]:

Comment: 2015-07-30T20:31:21.864914+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: rmarkdown version: NA
2015-07-30T20:31:21.864916+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: knitr version: NA
2015-07-30T20:31:21.864917+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: jsonlite version: 0.9.16
2015-07-30T20:31:21.864928+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: RJSONIO version: NA
2015-07-30T20:31:21.864970+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: htmltools version: 0.2.6
201